# Ambiguous/redundant delete/deletion tags

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

There seems to be a bunch of redundant tags here, made worse by inconsistent tag wikis.

- What's the fundamental difference between [comment-deletion](/questions/tagged/comment-deletion) and [deleted-comments](/questions/tagged/deleted-comments)? (Only the latter has a wiki.)
- What's the fundamental difference between [delete](/questions/tagged/delete) and [deletion](/questions/tagged/deletion)? (Only the former has a wiki.)
- Further, the tag wiki for [delete](/questions/tagged/delete) would seem to indicate it is a synonym of [deleted-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts)
- <del>If we have [deleted-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts), do we need [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) or [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers)?</del>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could argue that with the  *-deletion  tags you would ask questions about the process or actions needed to reach a certain state. Which might be useful for processes or actions that take forever or are error-prone and therefor generate enough questions and corner cases to warrant their own tags.

For something that is literally one-click and a confirm popup I don't think that will generate enough corner cases or lost users to make those tags very useful in finding posts related to that.  Or we must factoring in the review queues here but they have their own tags.

So my advice would be to burninate [comment-deletion](/questions/tagged/comment-deletion) and [deletion](/questions/tagged/deletion) <sup>1</sup>

I do think [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) and [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers) are useful and shouldn't be a synonym of [deleted-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts). The reasons a question or answer can be deleted are not the same (I think about Roomba, queues, votes) and the approach to have either an answer or question undeleted might differ. So I rather have a distinct tag for those as opposed to having two tags: [deleted-post](/questions/tagged/deleted-post) [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)

---

<sub>1. when this gets enough support I'll bring in the progress format found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/578411)</sub>

Comment: I would tend to agree about the "state" vs. "process" categorization. The only other `*-deletion` tag is [tag:tag-deletion]. Everything else is `deleted-*` (except there's no `deleted-tag`). It'd be nice to have some consistency.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'm all for consistency